# Propositional Logic conversion (English to Language of Logic)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I have a confusion about the below proposition logic:

Let ***p*** and ***q*** be the propositions

**p** :It is below freezing.

**q** :It is snowing.

Write these propositions using **p** and **q** and logical connectives (including negations).

1. It is either snowing or below freezing (or both). Answer: **p** or **q**
2. Either it is below freezing or it is snowing. What will be the Answer.
   Is it **p** or **q** or **p** xor **q**

Comment: (p and ~q) or (q and ~p)

Comment: How? Could you explain in details.

Comment: either it is below freezing or it is snowing means only one of the statements can be true. So, it is equivalent to saying "it is below freezing and it is NOT snowing" or "it is snowing and it is NOT below freezing".

Comment: I don't agree that the presence of "either" magically transforms "or" into "xor". This is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Natural languages are ambiguous but if the second sentence should be interpreted as it is one of those situation but not both then you could "translate" it as $(p \lor q) \land \lnot(p \land q)$, which is equivalent to $p \iff \lnot q$ which is also equivalent to what user137481 said. That's just because of the deffinition of the exclusive disjunction (xor).